# Replacing the word from specific string from a file

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have a file with pipe separated values. I want to replace `₩` with `W`.

```sh
Aron|14-jan|DC|US|9908
Mary|22-jun|Ma₩|US|134
John|12-may|houston|US|668
Carl|16-jun|Hawai|US|980
```

I fetched the value into a variable but I'm not able to replace it. I tried using `sed`.

```sh
DIR="/app/docu/File"
Variable=`awk 'NR==2' $DIR/$FILE | awk -F\| '{print $3}'`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`

If you want to replace all instances —

```sh
sed -e 's/₩/W/g' <file-name>
```

If you want to replace the instance only on 2<sup>nd</sup> line —

```
sed -e '2 s/₩/W/g' <file-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed  '2s/[^|]*/&\n/3;2s/\o342\o202\o251\n/W/' file
```

Identify the last character in third field of line two as `₩` and replace it by `W`.

N.B. Use `sed -n l file` to identify the octal value for `₩` as `\342\202\251`